# excludePathPatterns Not Working -- Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have a controller class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/wha")
public class Controlla {

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> hollow(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body) {
        return body;
    }
}
```

And an interceptor class which intercepts the request. This is how I add the interceptor:

```
@Bean
public Interc inter() {
    return new Interc();
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(inter())
            .addPathPatterns("/**")
            .excludePathPatterns("/**/wha/**");
}
```

The request does get intercepted, but it's like the `excludePathPatterns` is not even there. It doesn't work. I'm running Spring version 4.2.4.RELEASE. I've looked around on the internet and stack overflow but still couldn't get this resolved.

Comment: Could it be because your request is map on top level path `"/wha` while your interceptor pattern exclude on child path `"/**/wha/**"`? Have you tried to exclude `"/wha/**"`?

Comment: @DJ. I've tried `/wha/**` but that didn't work either

Comment: How about `"/**/wha"`?

Comment: @DJ. Yeah, that doesn't work. I'm not sure what the problem could be

Comment: What is the actual URL you are calling.

Comment: I opened my computer today, built and ran it, and everything works as expected -.- even though yesterday I would close terminal completely, reopen it, and run my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a complete reboot of my system, shutting it down and turning it back on again, everything worked as expected.